# Cross-Compiling ROS for the Nao Ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte

Tags: ubuntu, nao, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, cross-compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

##Problem on starting the roscore on a Nao v3##

Thanks to Daniel Maier there is a ros wiki page [how to compile cross compile ROS for a NAO with a Geode processor](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Tutorials/Cross-Compiling).
But I the description is not up-to-date and I have problems with the following constellation:

##The environment ##

- Ubuntu 12.04 (32bit)
- Nao V3.x (NaoQi 1.12.5)
- ROS fuerte

Is there someone who has a nice "how to" recipe?

##My error messages ##
With my recipe below I am getting the following error on starting the roscore at the Nao robot:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nao/ros-cross/ros/fuerte/bin/roscore", line 4, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

or on starting rospack

```
rospack: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.46.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

##My recipe which does not work! Not yet :-) ##
This is my recipe but it does not work --> it differs to the original wiki-description by an other installation path and it just compiles the roscore with no extra stuff.

```
# set environment variables 
export ROS_CROSS_ROOT=/home/nao/ros-cross #this is where ROS will be installed to, see below
export ROS_CROSS_DIR=$ROS_CROSS_ROOT/ros #this is where ROS will be installed to, see below
export AL_DIR="$HOME/opt/v.1.12.5-RoboCup/naoqi"
export CTC_DIR="$AL_DIR/crosstoolchain" # path to Aldebaran's cross-compilation toolchain (CTC)
export GEODE_CXX=$CTC_DIR/cross/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g++
export GEODE_CC=$CTC_DIR/cross/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH= # just to be sure

ll $GEODE_CXX    # just to test the path
ll $GEODE_CC     # just to test the path

sudo mkdir -p $ROS_CROSS_ROOT
sudo chown -R $USER $ROS_CROSS_ROOT
cd $ROS_CROSS_ROOT

#fuerte
rosinstall --catkin $ROS_CROSS_ROOT/ros-underlay http://ros.org/rosinstalls/fuerte-ros-base.rosinstall

cp $ROS_CROSS_ROOT/ros-underlay/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake $ROS_CROSS_ROOT/ros-underlay/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake.bak
echo "include(\"$CTC_DIR/toolchain-geode.cmake\")" >> $ROS_CROSS_ROOT/ros-underlay/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake
echo "include_directories(\"$ROS_CROSS_DIR/ros-deps/include\")" >>  $ROS_CROSS_ROOT/ros-underlay/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake
echo "link_directories(\"$ROS_CROSS_DIR/ros-deps/lib\")" >>  $ROS_CROSS_ROOT/ros-underlay/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake


gedit ./ros/core/rosbuild/private.cmake
# --> replace find_file(_file_name ${file} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} /) with find_file(_file_name ${file} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} / NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH)

cd $ROS_CROSS_ROOT/ros-underlay
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$ROS_CROSS_DIR/fuerte ..
make install
source $ROS_CROSS_DIR/fuerte/setup.sh
rosmake ros

#rosinstall $ROS_CROSS_DIR/fuerte/stacks "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=fuerte&variant=desktop&overlay=no"
cd rosinstall $ROS_CROSS_DIR/fuerte/stacks "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=fuerte&variant=ros-base&overlay=no"

rsync -zrptLv --delete-after -e "ssh" --exclude 'ros-underlay' --exclude 'boost' $ROS_CROSS_ROOT nao@IP-ROBOT:./
```

Thanks
Max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38374/cross-compiling-ros-for-the-nao-ubuntu-12.04-and-fuerte/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2013-05-20**:
did you test running roscore in your computer within your current ros installation path before copying to the robot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using the newer Nao too. I decided to install ROS electric (desktop), ubuntu 10.04 with the atom toolchain 1.12.5. Today it compiles onto the pc. Buuut, ROS still doesnt run into the NAO. I attatch you my environment path bash with two boost paths that I included and solved a similar problem with boost.

```
#!/bin/sh
# set some environment variables for compiling
export TARGETDIR=~ #this is where ROS will be installed to, see below
export CTC_DIR=/path/to/nao-cross-toolchain-dir/nao-atom-cross-toolchain-1.12.5.3_2012-06-03 # path to Aldebaran's cross-compilation toolchain (CTC)
export ATOM_CXX=$CTC_DIR/cross/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g++
export ATOM_CC=$CTC_DIR/cross/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc
export ROS_BOOST_ROOT="${CTC_DIR}/sysroot/usr"
export ROS_BOOST_VERSION="1.45.0"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH= # just to be sure
echo Paths seteados correctamente...
```

---

Originally posted by [LeonardoLeottau](https://answers.ros.org/users/3140/leonardoleottau/) with karma: 58 on 2012-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0